# How does a USB-C to Lighting Adapter work / How to replace them?

Tags: usb, adapter, usb-c, lighting, replacement

So, I am fairly new here, and to be honest I have no clue if this is the right place to ask.

I am currently thinking about replacing a Lightning port with a USB-C port, just for power supply. At first I thought, if I were to just take a USB-C port and wire everything according to the pinouts, the device should work just fine. But then I realized, that most cables or adapters have a little chip inside. I assume this is for the logic that happens there, e.g. regulating data input and output and power input and output.

I wanted to understand how a USB-C to Lighting adapter really works, as this might help me with replacing them. Unfortunately I could not find any blueprints for the adapter.

I did find some images on how the pinouts of both of these work, would it be sufficient to wire those accordingly? Is this chip I was talking about necessary for a power supply?
Can anyone help me with this? An article about how they are made, a blueprint or pretty much anything.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
My goal is to replace the Lightning port with a USB-C port on the gen 1 airpods charging case. To learn more about this I first wanted to experiment with the connectors etc. As a start I wanted to make a cable going from USB-C to Lighting adapter and charge the Airpod Case this way.

Comment: On what device is the lightning port currently on ? Do you want to power the device with the lightning port or do you want to use it to power *another* device ? Is the port already capable of charging the device currently ? If not, the port wont have a connection to the device's battery and no amount of wiring will help it receive / deliver power. Please [edit] more info into the question. Even then it may be off topic for this SE.

Comment: Hey there. I edited the question as you requested. Are these the information you asked for? I know that with something that small as Airpods it might be impossible to implement USB-C charging, but once I started thinking about I was rather interested in how to do this in generel. I already assumed this might be off topic but I didn´t find anyplace else. By any chance, could you recommend a better place to look for these kind of information?

Comment: I think the chip is mostly to make sure you've paid the licensing fee  to use the port. I doubt the specifications are available without signing a license agreement first.

Comment: Perhaps you could solder wires to the ground and power lines of the Lightning connector on the PCB and see if supplying it with 5 V is sufficient for it to work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That is what I first thought as well. But to be honest, I don´t really know that much about this kinda stuff, and I wanted to research as much as possible. But I guess that´s what I´ll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @appa first of all you have to know the differences between USB-C and Lightning connectors concerning charging applications as you intend to use. So i will not point to any other information rather than powering or charging purposes. Just to not confuse you with too much un-needed informations.

USB-C has 24 pins that can handle up to 100w of power (20v/5A), on the other hand Lightnings have 8 pins that are able to handle just 12w of power. So replacing Lightning by USB-C could be safe.

Secondly referring to USB-C connector pinouts "figure 1" and Lightning connector pinouts "figure 2" you can connect the power lines together (GND - > GND & VBUS -> PWR) and see if this could deliver only power to airpods charging device, although I have never tried to do so and I recommend you to take adequate safety precautions as this could cause real injury or  might damage your airpods, charging device, or supply device.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Also I think the chips that you are talking about are for communication purposes, it might not affect your desire to power up your device.

For more information about USB-C and Lightning comparisons refer to this article [Link](https://www.tronsmart.com/blog/47_5-reasons-why-usb-c-is-better-than-lightning.html)

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I stumbled across these figures, but as you assumed I was kind of confused by the other pins. I guess I will try connecting ground and power and see how that works out.

If my USB-C puts out 60w (laptop charger) can I use the same cable for the airpods? I assume they need way less and I don´t want it to overheat. How can I prevent that from happening? I would be happy with some keywords so that I can look it up myself. Sorry if my questions sound foolish.

Comment: @Appa there is no inconvenience at all, here in Stack Exchange we try to share knowledge to spread useful informations that any one can refer to it whenever needed. and that's why I honestly love this community.

Comment: So your airpod charger is for sure designed to withdraw the max of 12w available by the Lightning connector, and this could be in the safe zone for USB-C connector that can supply 100w "2 channels 50w each" . Take in consideration that when saying USB-C connectors can deliver up to 100w it doesn't mean that each time it will supply 100w power for sure. I mean its dependant on the consumption of the connected device. in other words you can use USB-C connector to power 10w devices, 30w devices and max 100w devices.

Comment: So if would like some keywords to further expand your knowledge you can google search differences between USB2, USB3, USB-C transfer rates, USB supply ability. You will find information about devices like wireless mice, keyboards, speakers, and smart home devices, all either currently do, or could in the future, offer USB-C ports, both for power delivery and data transfer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your effort. I think my next step is to actually try it. I´ll keep researching and hopefully don´t mess up too much. And yeah, that´s right, Stack Exchange might be one of the healthiest communities.

Comment: Hi @Appa, were you able to make any progress on introducing USB-C port to AirPods? I'm looking into doing a similar thing for AirPods Pro

Comment: Hey @vanshg, some good news and some bad news. I managed to extend the case a little just a few mm so I could fit the usb c port in there, unfortunately I stumbled across a problem. afte I connected everything and plugged it in, the leds started to light up (always a good sign I guess) but when connected with an I Phone the pop up menu stated that it doesn't charge? I couldn't figure out how to solve this. My guess is that it has something to do with some authorization protocol from apple? Well this was as far as I went. My guess is, that you can fix that with more space and more tests...

Comment: @Appa Can you share the part link to the USB-C port that you used? I'm assuming the port didn't snap right into the main board - so, what technique did you use to wire it up?

Do you think this authorization issue could be solved if, for example, a part from a USB-C iPad was used?